# C create a matrix of Bignum

Tags: c, matrix, openssl, bignum

I'm trying to create a matrix in C where each element is a Bignum (from the Openssl librairy).
I was thinking it would be something like this but it doesn't work.

```
BIGNUM *p [2][2] = NULL;
  int i; int j;
  for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
      *p[i][j] = BN_new();
    }

  }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: This declaration  BIGNUM *p [2][2] = NULL; does not make sense.

Comment: what you ahve here is an 2d array of pointers to bignums. But you say you want a 2d array of bignums. So do `BIGNUM p[2][2]`

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the return type of `BN_new()` is `BIGNUM *`.

Since `BIGNUM *p[2][2]` is a 2*2 array and the data type of the elements is  `BIGNUM*`, the assignment to an element of the array `p`, would look like this:

```
p[i][j] = BN_new();
```

This means your code should look like this:

```
BIGNUM *p[2][2] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

for( int i=0; i<2; ++i ) {
    for( int j=0; j<2; ++j ) {
        p[i][j] = BN_new();
    }
}
```

The expression `*p[i][j]` would access a `BIGNUM` value indirectly, through the pointer `p[i][j]`. This works, because the index operator `[]` takes precedence over the indirection operator `*`.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the pointer dereferencing in *p[2][2] you are referencing an address too far. (The asterisk)

You should be able to use something like this:

```
BIGNUM p[2][2];

int i; int j;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
        p[i][j] = BN_new();
    }
}
```

There is another approach you could use where you say width=2 and height=2

```
BIGNUM *p = calloc(width * height, sizeof(BIGNUM));
```

Then you reference it with something like this (variables from your example):

```
p[i*width+j] = BN_new();
```